# add a linear layout on click of a button

Tags: android, layout

i want to add a linear layout which contains TextView and imageView whenever a button is clicked 
and the linear layouts that are added are also contained in another linear layout
so how am i supposed to do it

Comment: Please share your xml file

Comment: it is gonna be added on an empty activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

   final container findViewById(R.id.container);
   final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

   Button button = findViewbyId(R.id.button);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           addView(inflater, container)
       }
   });
}

private void addView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview_Label_layout, container, true);
}
```

Here your layout to inflate imageview_Label_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here your activity main_activity_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```